# Can a restaurant prohibit entry based on a non-uniformly enforced dress code?

Tags: customer-service

Can a restaurant bar a person from entry based on a dress code violation ("no trainers/sneakers", for example) that they do not enforce amongst their own staff?

Comment: Their staff are not patrons of the Resteraunt - they may well have a different code.

Comment: that is opposite of the accepted answer, can you defend your view? I'll accept if it's good and posted as an answer

Comment: I agree with the accepted answer; this is just another perspective

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, barring any statutory prohibitions against such a rule. I would be very surprised if any existed. They don't exist in any jurisdiction I'm familiar with. Look up the local by-laws to be sure.